# Python Timeout on a thread, without the use of join

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So I'm working on a TCP in python.

We are having a problem with threads not exiting properly.

We want it to have multiple connections, so when a new connection is spawned a new thread is started. However these threads don't always exit properly. They have return statements but when I run Thread.activeCount() I find that these build up.

I have no idea what the problem is. These threads build up, and then dissipate. I want to do a thread time out, however I don't want to use Thread.join() because if a new connection is established it won't go to the receive functions, which would cause the client to timeout due to a lack of response.

Any suggestions on a timeout command? I can't seem to find any on the python docs.

Comment: Seems like you have two problems, (1) the threads aren't exiting... which is why threadCount goes up - so you have to figure out why they never hit their exit points, and (2) when they do exit, you need a way to join the thread. That depends a lot on how your system is architected. Last ditch fallback is to have a list of threads and periodically poll them to see what needs cleaning.

Comment: I'd be more concerned as to why the threads aren't exiting properly. Potentially an XY problem. If something goes wrong they should throw an exception and exit. At least I would assume so. Another thing to consider is how to exit the threads cleanly. Merely stopping mid-execution could be dangerous.

Comment: Well I've been trying to see why they don't exit properly. I've put in several checks to make sure the loops will exit, and they do. In the log files they print lines right above a return statement, but the thread doesn't quit. The connections are closed, as new ones are started, and socket timeouts will trigger (been tested) and exit cleanly